# WP7 - Update ListPicker items asynchronous

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm

In this case isn't supposed that I can see the values from list in ListPicker?

**xaml**

```
<toolkit:ListPicker
                x:Name="lpkBoards"
                ItemsSource="{Binding AllBoards}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Name" >
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

**xaml.cs**

```
public SettingsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Set the page DataContext property to the ViewModel.
            this.DataContext = App.ViewModel;

         ...

            boardsTask.ContinueWith(
                (call) =>
                {
                    App.ViewModel.AllBoards = call.Result.ToList();

                }
                );
```

**ViewModel**

```
// All to-do items.
private List<Board> _allBoards;
public List<Board> AllBoards
{
    get { return _allBoards; }
    set
    {
        _allBoards = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("AllBoards");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any exception? Any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `List<Board>` to `ObservalbeCollection<Board>` if you are trying to bind it to a UI element and want it to work.

Comment: Good but only for the case when author add items one by one. There, I can see that author set entire collection in the property, so his approach should work.